# How to use iterator of static stl list?

Tags: c++, list, stl, static, iterator

I'm new to c++.

In my program I should have some 'global' list (that should initialized only once) and a function (both should be accessible from other classes ans files). I've defined it like this:

```
//header.h file    
#include <list>    
using namespace std;

class ClassA {
public:
    int Var;
};

class StaticListAndFunc {
    static list<ClassA> StaticListOfClassA;
    static return_t StaticFunc(int x, int y);
};
```

My static function should use StaticListOfClassA and some other simple inputs.
Now I'm trying to use the StaticListOfClassA to implement the StaticFunc in the source file:

```
//source.cpp
  #include "header.h"  
   return_t StaticListAndFunc::StaticFunc(int x, int y) {
        list<ClassA>::iterator TheIterator = StaticListOfClassA.begin();
        ...
};
```

The error I've got: "source.cpp: undefined reference to `ClassA::StaticListOfClassA'" (in the line list::iterator TheIterator = StaticListOfClassA.begin();)

How should I define the iterator right? Or maybe there is another better way to define a class that can be later easily accessible from other files and classes?
I really appreciate any help..

Comment: Your's in a *link* error, not a compile-time error. You never defined your class static var, you only declared it. It needs a home in some translation unit somewhere. Right above that function is looking like a tasty place to me.

Comment: `In my program I should have some 'global' list (that should initialized only once)` Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not define your static list. In source.cpp module you should write

```
list<ClassA> StaticListAndFunc::StaticListOfClassA;
```

that is you need to define this static data member.

Also take into account that you declared function StaticFunc as having private access control. You may not call it outside the class member functions or friend functions.